# EmberJS - How to update dateFrom Query Param with Pikaday input

Tags: javascript, ember.js, pikaday

I am using the following input from the [ember-pikaday](https://github.com/edgycircle/ember-pikaday) addon:

```
<div class="col-sm-3"><label>Date From:</label>{{pikaday-input value=dateFrom name="dateFrom" class="form-control"}}</div>
```

I cannot get the value of the input to update the query parameter in the URL. If I use a standard input it works with the following controller:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({

queryParams: ['dateFrom', 'dateTo', 'unitNumber'],
dateFrom: null,
dateTo: null,
unitNumber: null,

  actions: {
    selected(x){
      module = x
    },

    submitQuery(dateFrom, dateTo, unitNumber){
        switch(module) {
          case 'Option 1':
          this.transitionToRoute('option1', {queryParams: {dateFrom: this.get('dateFrom'), dateTo: this.get('dateTo'), unitNumber: this.get('unitNumber') }})
        break;
    }
   }
  }
});
```

I suspect I need an action when a date is selected but I do not know how to handle the update within the action. I tried the following:

```
//onSelection=(action 'select') added to pikday input

select() {
    dateFrom = this.set('dateFrom')
}
```

But it did not represent in the URL. I think that would be incorrect scoping anyway. I am still very new to Ember (and coding). Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here they mentioned how to use this package,
https://github.com/edgycircle/ember-pikaday#usage

```
{{pikaday-input onSelection=(action 'doSomethingWithSelectedValue')}}
```

In your case, you need to update the selected value from pikaday input to `dateFrom` property of the controller.

```
{{pikaday-input value=dateFrom name="dateFrom" class="form-control" onSelection=(action 'onChangeDateFrom') }}
```

define actions in the controller actions hash,

```
onChangeDateFrom(selectedValue)
{
 this.set('dateFrom',selectedValue);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I completely missed the Selected Value argument. The URL updates correctly but it is in a long form (Thu%20Nov%2002%202017%2000%3A00%3A00%20GMT%2B0000%20(GMT%20Standard%20Time)). I'll need to get that changed!  Marked the answer as correct :)

Comment: You can format it like the way you want, you can even use moment formatting in the way server accepts.